# Using For Loop To Count A Qr Code Scanner In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-framework-7

I am using a Qr Code Scanner from here : https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode

and I successfully start the scanner and it will return a result.

result that I want to achieve is scan the qr code 11 times, and append into a list.

PS: Using Framework7 Custom DOM so call with `$$`

I try to loop it :

```
$$(document).on('click', '#skvqr', function () {
  Html5Qrcode.getCameras().then(devices => {
    /**
     * devices would be an array of objects of type:
     * { id: "id", label: "label" }
     */
    if (devices && devices.length) {
      var cameraId = devices[1].id;
      // .. use this to start scanning.

      const html5QrCode = new Html5Qrcode(/* element id */ "reader");
      html5QrCode.start(
        cameraId,
        {
          fps: 10,    // Optional frame per seconds for qr code scanning
          qrbox: 200  // Optional if you want bounded box UI
        },
        qrCodeMessage => {
          // do something when code is read
          alert("scan succesful " + qrCodeMessage)
          for (i = 11; i >= 1; --i) {
            alert("scan succesful " + qrCodeMessage + " Press Ok and Scan " + i + " more times")
  
             $$("#qr-scan-3").append('<input type="text" value=" ' + 'SKV : ' + qrCodeMessage + ' " placeholder="Qr Scan 1">' +
            '<span class="input-clear-button"></span>'
          );
          this.style.display = 'none'
          html5QrCode.stop().then(ignore => {
            // QR Code scanning is stopped.
          }).catch(err => {
            // Stop failed, handle it.
          });

          }

         
        },
        errorMessage => {
          // parse error, ignore it.
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // Start failed, handle it.
        });
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }).catch(err => {
    // handle err
  });
});
```

and it's return me 11 times alert

```
("scan succesful " + qrCodeMessage + " Press Ok and Scan " + i + " more times")
```

and it only scan for the first time.

Please help me, still learning on JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'd need to maintain a state that is global to the success callback.

```
// define the scanner object
const html5QrCode = new Html5Qrcode(/* element id */ "reader");

let matchesFound = 0;
const totalScansNeeded = 11;
var successCallback = qrCodeMessage => {
    matchesFound++;
    if (matchesFound < totalScansNeeded) {
        let remainingScans = totalScansNeeded - matchesFound;
        alert(`scan successful ${qrCodeMessage}. Press Ok `
            + `and Scan ${remainingScans} more times"`);
    } else {
        // .. expected matches found
        // .. do required UI changes
        html5QrCode.stop().then(ignore => {
          // QR Code scanning is stopped.
        }).catch(err => {
          // Stop failed, handle it.
        });
    }
}
```

And then consume it in the actual listener

```
$$(document).on('click', '#skvqr', function () {
  Html5Qrcode.getCameras().then(devices => {
    if (devices && devices.length) {
      var cameraId = devices[1].id;
      html5QrCode.start(
        cameraId,
        { fps: 10,  qrbox: 200 },
        successCallback)
        .catch(err => {
          // Start failed, handle it.
        });
    }
  });
});
```